# Nodemon [filename.js] returns bash: nodemon: command not found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, git-bash, nodemon

I can't get nodemon running. I've tried installing it with `npm install -g nodemon` and `npm install nodemon --save-dev`. When I run `npm list -g --depth=0` it shows nodemon is installed. But for the life of me, can't get it to work. Any help please?

Comment: Where is `npm` installing binary stubs? Is that location in your PATH?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you explain a bit further?

Comment: When you install a library in a language that lets those libraries bundle executable scripts (`npm install` and all its equivalents for different languages -- `pip install`, `gem install`, etc etc), they're going to install those executable wrappers... well... *somewhere*. Exactly where that somewhere is depends on configuration, typically including whether you're running `npm` as root or as yourself, and whether you're using something like [`nodeenv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv/).

Comment: ...regardless, wherever that ends up being, your shell needs to know about it -- that's the job of the `PATH` variable.

Comment: ...so, we know you used `npm install -g`, which means you were installing into the global location. Running `npm root -g`, then, will tell us where the base of that location is; the location that needs to be in your PATH will be relative to it.

Comment: For instance, if it's `/usr/local/node_modules`, then maybe you need `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/node_modules/.bin`.

Comment: It gives `C:\Users\rmcgu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` still a bit confused on how to proceed.

Comment: And is there a `.bin` directory under that `node_modules` directory that contains `nodemon`?

Comment: ...I suppose on Windows it might be something like `nodemon.exe` or such; might even have a name other than `.bin` -- platform-specific implementation details are liable to matter. Point is, though, somewhere under that root there'll be a runnable script or executable; you need to find it, and adjust your shell's PATH.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have a bin folder which contains nodemon.js but no .exe

Comment: Probably `.js` is configured to be executable. Anyhow, when you tell Git Bash to run the script in that folder as a command, does it work? If so, go ahead and add the folder to your PATH. If not, then we need to dig into the why and how. (Does `ls -l nodemon.js`, in the directory in question, reflect `+x` permissions?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I figured it out. Had to setup npm's in my PATH. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to go into my `Path` and set the route for my npms.

Here's how you do it:

1. Find your path for nodemon (or any npm) in nodemons case you can type `where nodemon` this will give you the file location. Mine was `C:\Users\rmcgu\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon` copy that file path.
2. Search windows for system and then advanced system settings.
3. This opens a new window called system properties. From here click on the `advanced` tab and then `Environment Variables...`
4. Then under User variables for username, there will be a few options. In my case, OneDrive, Path, Temp and TMP. Click `path` and then `edit...`
5. On the new window (Edit environment variable) click `new` and past your previously copied file path in, but remove anything after `\npm` So for example `C:\Users\rmcgu\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon` becomes `C:\Users\rmcgu\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Hopefully this helps someone else out. I had `C:\Users\rmcgu\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon` set in my path, but not the npm directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add how I fixed this issue, as I had to do a bit of mix and match from a few different solutions. For reference this is for a Windows 10 PC, nodemon had worked perfectly for months and then suddenly the command was not found unless run locally with npx. 
Here were my steps -

1. Check to see if it is installed globally by running `npm list -g
   --depth=0`, in my case it was installed, so to start fresh...
2. I ran `npm uninstall -g nodemon`
3. Next, I reinstalled using `npm install -g --force nodemon --save-dev` (it might be recommended to try running `npm install -g nodemon --save-dev` first, go through the rest of the steps, and if it doesn't work go through steps 2 & 3 again using --force).
4. Then I checked where my npm folder was located with the command `npm config get prefix`, which in my case was located at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
5. I modified my PATH variable to add both that file path and a second entry with \bin appended to it (I am not sure which one is actually needed as some people have needed just the root npm folder and others have needed bin, it was easy enough to simply add both)
6. Finally, I followed directions from another similar question, which recommended editing the .bashrc file from your ~ directory. However, with Windows, the .bashrc file doesn't automatically exist, so you need to create one in your ~ directory. I also needed to slightly alter how the export was written for Windows (so if you have Ubuntu or Linux, I recommend searching for the correct format for the .bashrc file). For mine, I used `export PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;` (Obviously replace "username" with whatever your username is, or whatever the file path was that was retrieved in step 4)

I hope this helps anyone who has been struggling with this issue for as long as I have!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so you're on Windows. If you're on Linux/Unix:

Here's how you do it:

Find your path for nodemon (or any npm). In nodemons case you can type

```
find / -name nodemon
```

This will give you the file location. Add this directory to your path:

```
echo 'PATH=/the/directory/from/find/output:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

(note: single quotes; assuming you're using bash)

Comment: `find /` is far too broad -- if a machine has 10 different users who have all run `npm install nodemon`, this would include every one of their installations. The search should start at the location returned by `npm root`, or `npm root -g` if the install was done with `npm install -g`.

Comment: That said, I believe the `git-bash` tag marked this as a Windows question from the beginning ("Git Bash" is the msys-based shell environment installed alongside common Windows distributions of Git).

Comment: For the find: you only do it once to add it to your PATH in your profile, and I agree that if you're using personal installations, `~` would probably be better than `/` for the find. As for the windows-tag: I stand corrected. Feel free to downvote me.

Comment: It's not just about speed, it's about finding the correct install on a multi-user system or one with virtualenv-style multiple roots. Even `~` isn't necessarily right -- if you have one npm root you use for Project A and a different npm root for Project B (as Python developers often have a `virtualenv` per project so as to allow separate library versions to be used), you only want to look under the currently appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
sudo npm install -g --force nodemon
```

and it worked for me.